# Get video id from youtube link

Tags: javascript, hyperlink, youtube

i have this line:

```
token = videos.results[i].titlemay_link.split("?v=")[1];
```

videos.results[i].titlemay_link = the link to a youtube video en the split only returns the code.

now the problem is that some youtube links i get are links like this:

```
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1zO9nWgI_LY&feature=youtu.be
```

so the output i get is:

```
1zO9nWgI_LY&feature=youtu.be
```

this will not load the video in the embed player, how can i get rid of the

```
&feature=youtu.be
```

thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
token = videos.results[i].titlemay_link.split("?v=")[1];
token = token.split("&")[0];
```

But that won't be sufficient in most of the cases as youtube URLs gets complicated many times, here is a more roust method to fetch the youtube video ID

```
function youtube_parser(url){
    var regExp = /^.*((youtu.be\/)|(v\/)|(\/u\/\w\/)|(embed\/)|(watch\?))\??v?=?([^#\&\?]*).*/;
    var match = url.match(regExp);
    return (match&&match[7].length==11)? match[7] : false;
}
```

**These are the types of URLs supported**

```
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0zM3nApSvMg&feature=feedrec_grec_index
http://www.youtube.com/user/IngridMichaelsonVEVO#p/a/u/1/QdK8U-VIH_o
http://www.youtube.com/v/0zM3nApSvMg?fs=1&amp;hl=en_US&amp;rel=0
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0zM3nApSvMg#t=0m10s
http://www.youtube.com/embed/0zM3nApSvMg?rel=0
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0zM3nApSvMg
http://youtu.be/0zM3nApSvMg
```

Answer (score 1):

Add one more condition after you get `token` and check using **[`.contains`](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.contains/)** as below:

```
if(token.contains('&'))
   token=token.split('&')[0];
```